# Armature Symmetrizing Problems

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

One of my bones is simple not symmetrizing with the rest of its compatriots. I have  tried symmetrizing it by itself to no avail. It simply refuses to cooperate.

Anyone had this problem &/^ found a fix/work around?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little silly answering my own question so quickly, but this was easy to miss so it is best to make sure it is documented.

The shin didn't symmetrize because the name was ever so slightly off. I had "shin.L**.**" instead of "shin.L". That extra *dot* on the end was enough to confuse Blender into not working properly.

Keep a sharp eye on your bone's names.